# calculate annual expected sales based on sales of January and changes in percentage compared to last month

Tags: excel, formula

I would like to know whether it is possible to use an excel formula to calculate this:

A1 is the sales value of January.
A2 is the change in percentage of sales in February compared to January. (ex: -2%, +23.5%)
A3 is the change in percentage of sales in March compared to February.
A4 for April, and A12 for December.

In A13, can we use an excel formula to calculate the annual expected sales?
I don't want to manually type the formula such as =A1+A1*(1+A2)+A1*(1+A2)*(1+A3) ...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is using column B allowed?  B2 = A1*A2. Then B3 = B2*A3 and copy down.

Comment: yes thanks but I manage several shops and several shops' data are arranged in a table. To add columns at the right of each column and then copy+paste is also burdensome. So I just wanted to know if there is a shortcut.

Comment: There are some mysterious functions in the 'finance' category such as fv, accrint, cumprinc, ispmt, etc... But I cannot dare touch them at all haha

Comment: If you can't create more cells for the monthly estimates, this ends up being a long formula...

Answer (score 1):

This User Defined Function will do what you ask:

```
Function suminc(st As Double, rng As Range) As Double
Application.Volatile
Dim inc() As Variant
Dim temp() As Double
Dim i As Long


If Not IsNumeric(st) Then
    suminc = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    Exit Function
End If
inc = rng.Value
ReDim temp(1 To UBound(inc, 1) + 1)

temp(1) = st

For i = 2 To UBound(inc, 1) + 1
    If IsNumeric(inc(i - 1, 1)) Then
        temp(i) = temp(i - 1) * (1 + inc(i - 1, 1))
    Else
        suminc = CVErr(xlErrValue)
        Exit Function
    End If
Next i
suminc = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(temp)
End Function
```

Put it in a module attached to the workbook, **NOT** The worksheet code or ThisWorkbook code.

Then in the Sheet you would call it like this:

```
=suminc(A1,A2:A12)
```

The first is the starting number, the second the range that contains the monthly increase in percentage.

[image]

Comment: Can you please write a macro that will do my laundry?

Comment: How does it know to use the value of `a1` when you do `temp(1) = st` and not the range `a1`? Because you indicated you were passing a double?

Comment: @findwindow magic!  Range objects are Variant and therefore can be made to fit many types.  As I understand it will fail if a number is not passed to the UDF.